# The length -1 is not valid for function "SUBSTRING". The length parameter cannot be negative in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to convert a data from a flat file to a SQL date. I am using variables to separate the Month, Day, and Year and added necessary "0" when needed then concatenate them back together. the job works fine except when I run into a date that is blank and it throws out three errors: "The length -1 is not valid for function "SUBSTRING". The length parameter cannot be negative. Change the length parameter to zero or a positive value.", "Evaluating function "SUBSTRING" failed with error code 0xC004708B.", AND "Evaluating function "LEN" failed with error code 0xC00470C5.". I have a variable for the date ***1/2/1995*** to find the "/" using Y `FINDSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , "/", 1 )`

and then the example I have for the month is

```
@[User::Y] < 1 ?  (DT_STR, 2, 1252) NULL(DT_STR, 2, 1252) :  (LEN( SUBSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , 1, @[User::Y] -1 )) < 2 ? "0" + SUBSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , 1, @[User::Y] -1 ) : SUBSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , 1, @[User::Y] -1 ))
```

As I said, the expression works fine if there is a date, but if it is blank then I receive an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `@[User::Scan_Date]` is null using `ISNULL()` function, if it is null you can return a  blank string or NULL value, else calculate your expression.

```
ISNULL(@[User::Scan_Date]) ? "" : 
(@[User::Y] < 1 ?  (DT_STR, 2, 1252) NULL(DT_STR, 2, 1252) :  (LEN( SUBSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , 1, @[User::Y] -1 )) < 2 ? "0" + SUBSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , 1, @[User::Y] -1 ) : SUBSTRING( @[User::Scan_Date] , 1, @[User::Y] -1 )))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole expression in an `IIF` that checks to see if the date is blank.